# How to create a overlapping border with different colors and widths / heights on a input element?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently working on a drag and drop web app with vue.js
In this app, we have some special designed borders on an input HTML element.

The designs look like this: (ignore the grey vertical line. This is drawn dynamically)
[image]

I have tried something like creating a sibling div an make it a little bit larger than the input, set it with z-index behind the input and set a color. But the problem is that the light blue border-right and border-left will always take 100% of the height. I need something like 75% or 80%.

The "overlapping" border can also be on the top, right or left on an element
[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have a clue for the best way to solve this problem responsive?

Comment: you could play with pseudo css classes :before and :after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

border-image with gradient is what you need:

```css
input {
  border:2px solid;
  padding:10px;
  background:pink;
}
.one {
  border-image:linear-gradient(to right, red 80%,blue 0) 2;
}
.two {
  border-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,red 70%,blue 0) 2;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="one">

<input type="text" class="two">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :after and :before for the borders that cover the remaining 20%.

```
<div><input value="Text"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
  padding:20px;
  border: 5px solid lightblue;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}
div:before {
  content:' ';
  width:5px;
  height: 14px;
  background:gray;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:999;
}
div:after {
  content:' ';
  width:5px;
  height: 14px;
  background:gray;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:999; 
}
div {position: relative;width:fit-content;}
```

See example: https://codepen.io/MistaPrime/pen/XWryOOy

Answer (score 0):

I would probably style the wrapping element and add psuedo elements on it.

https://codepen.io/slackday/pen/wvwQOvq

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>How to create a overlapping border with different colors and widths / heights on a input element?</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .site {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .input-wrapper {
      position: relative;
    }

    .input-wrapper::before,
    .input-wrapper::after {
      height: 20%; /* adjust height of how much it should overlap */
      width: 1px; /* same width as your input border */
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      content: '';
      background-color: #ccc; /** same color as bottom border */
    }

    .input-wrapper::before {
      left: 0;
    }

    .input-wrapper::after {
      right: 0;
    }

    input {
      border: solid 1px aqua;
      border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
      position: relative; /* to position psuedo elements ::before, ::after */
      padding: 1rem;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1;
    }

    input:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <main class="site">
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" value="text" placeholder="Aorta" />
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```